# Android TextInputLayout - Once setting endIconMode to END_ICON_NONE, unable to set it back to END_ICON_CLEAR_TEXT programeticaly

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a TextInputLayout which has endIconMode set to TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CLEAR_TEXT.

I set the endIconMode to TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE programetically but when I set it again to TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CLEAR_TEXT, it will not re-appear.

I dont have any custom listeners or anything. Simply setting the icon mode to END_ICON_NONE and disable the control. Then I re-enable the control and set it back to END_ICON_CLEAR_TEXT.

Comment: Can you provide your code. I just tested it, it works correctly.

Comment: @ObscureCookie, 
Thanx alot. I found a fix and added as the answer.  Its difficult to post the code because in many locations it sets the icon mode and enable/disable the control. Thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the reason but I found a fix.

Adding textInputLayout.clearOnEndIconChangedListeners() before setting the icon mode did the trick. Not sure what was wrong and not sure the impact of clearing above listeners.

Thanx alot